# Facebook Places API incomplete & incorrect response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app is having issues with getting facebook page data: "rating_count" & "overall_star_rating". The issue have been found about 20 hours ago, between 2 am UTC to 6 am UTC 12th of October, so probably it's on Facebook side.

For example, request to all graph versions older 2.8 would same response:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/pageID?fields=overall_star_rating,rating_count&access_token=YourToken

```
{
   "overall_star_rating": 0,
   "rating_count": 0,
   "id": "pageID"
}
```

Look at zero counts - blank for all the pages. It doesn't matter what token you're using - app/user/page one, response is the same.

Requesting newer API versions (v2.10 & v2.9) give similar, but worth (incomplete) response:

```
{
   "rating_count": 0,
   "id": "pageID"
}
```

Both counts, "overall_star_rating" & "rating_count" are valid according to documentation.

Did anyone experience the issue? How did you fix it?

BTW, if you request "ratings" along with counts, but you'll have to use Page Access Token for that, you'll get an array of reviews of the page, but zero stats. I'm thinking of counting reviews & calculating rating based on them, but this way is wrong for many reasons.

Comment: There are a lot of general issues right now, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/209266032946304/

Comment: Looks like Facebook team picked this up : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1816620328365587/

Comment: This should be fixed now :)